# UIScrollView not scrolling with large height

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have controller with UIScrollView in it, and in iPad version there is no scrolling from up to bottow. I explicitly set content size height like that:

```
  CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width-4, 2500);
    // assume self is the content view
    CGRect newFrame = (CGRect){CGPointZero,newSize}; // Assuming you want to start at the top-left corner of the scroll view. Change CGPointZero as appropriate
    [self.mainScroll setContentSize:newSize];
```

Even in debugger, when i print description of `scrollView` i see following:

```
<UIScrollView: 0x7fc12486e400; frame = (0 0; 768 960); clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fc1259cf830>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc1259a45e0>; contentOffset: {0, 765}; contentSize: {764, 2500}>
(lldb)
```

As you can see, content size is set to 2500, however, i cant scroll anything. And i obviously check, that scrolling enabled is YES..

Also, main scroll view is bound to main view with constraints like top-left-right-bottom with value of 0. But, even when i increase height of self view, still, no effect.

How to force it to scroll??

Comment: Scrolling it enabled, but is user interaction enabled?  Also, are there any other views in the view heirarchy that might be intercepting the touch events? Implement  `(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` and `(void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` and put some breakpoints in there.

Comment: @wottle yes, its enabled. I implement those 2 methods and it output my text in console when i try to drag view.. in (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView

Comment: Have you printed the `frame` and `contentSize` of the Scrollview in the `(void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` method?  I wonder if the contentSize if getting updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're using auto layout. An attempt to set, in code, the `contentSize` of a scroll view under auto layout will fail. Scroll view content size under auto layout works in a completely different way: you use as the scroll view's sole immediate subview a container view, sized by internal constraints to the content size and pinned on all four sides to the scroll view with a `constant` of zero.

Comment: This is a downloadable project that illustrates the principle: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/tree/master/bk2ch07p367scrollViewInNibAutolayout2

Comment: i appreciate your explanation, will download project asap. Considering getting your book. :)